# Como realizar operaçao com union

Tags: sql

Pessoal estou tentando fazer uma operação com essa duas query mas não sei como.

```
select 
sum(total_atend) total_atend,
sum(total_infect) total_infet

From (
select count(atendime.tp_atendimento) total_atend, 0 total_infect
from atendime, paciente
where atendime.cd_paciente = paciente.cd_paciente
and tp_atendimento = 'I'
and to_char(dt_atendimento,'mm/yyyy') = '12/2014'
---and cd_ori_ate = 3
and cd_atendimento_pai is null

union 

select 0 total_atend, count(tp_infec) total_infect from reg_inf total_infect
where to_char(dt_reg_inf,'mm/yyyy') = '12/2014' )
```

Esse `select` acima retorna os dados

[image: resultadoactual]

O que preciso é fazer uma operação com esses 2 selects

que me retorne:

```
Total_atend, Total_Infet, Taxa_Infec*
```

*(essa `Taxa_Infec` seria a `total_infet/total_atend` x `100`)

Comment: Porque você não joga em uma tabela temporária, acho que ficaria mais fácil manipulá-la!

Comment: Só uma pergunta, talvez não faça diferença, você está usando Oracle ou postgresql?

Comment: é oracle, desculpa nao ter respondido ontem, mas o que Allan fez embaixo deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, não consegui testar aqui, mas isso deveria funcionar:

```
select 
sum(total_atend) total_atend,
sum(total_infect) total_infet,
((sum(total_infect)/sum(total_atend) ) * 100) taxa_infec

From (
select count(atendime.tp_atendimento) total_atend, 0 total_infect
from atendime, paciente
where atendime.cd_paciente = paciente.cd_paciente
and tp_atendimento = 'I'
and to_char(dt_atendimento,'mm/yyyy') = '12/2014'
---and cd_ori_ate = 3
and cd_atendimento_pai is null

union 

select 0 total_atend, count(tp_infec) total_infect from reg_inf total_infect
where to_char(dt_reg_inf,'mm/yyyy') = '12/2014' )
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!! Me ajudou muito!